# How to best transition a book app that uses one UIViewController to handle all the pages as UIViews to StoryBoarding and UIPageView?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uipageviewcontroller

I have a book app that has about 30 pages that are each a UIView in a single UIViewController.  I want to transition this to an app that uses StoryBoarding and UIPageViews.  It looks like each of the "pages" in UIPageView must be a UIViewController, not a UIView.  What would be the best way of going about this?  Do I need to make a UIViewController out of each UIView page?

Comment: Check out [An Example iOS 5 iPhone UIPageViewController Application](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application)

Comment: @beryllium too bad you can't award bounties to comments, cuz this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [An Example iOS 5 iPhone UIPageViewController Application](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application) article. That chapter will provide a brief overview of the concepts behind the page view controller and an example application designed to demonstrate this class in action.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Rewrite all your `UIView` subclasses as `UIViewController` subclasses. I've done it with a few of my projects, and it turns out to be just a little tedious. For my projects I found it easiest to just create a new Xcode project and build the new infrastructure. Then create new `UIViewController` classes for each of my old `UIView` classes. Then I copied and pasted most of the code from the old `UIView` classes into new `UIViewController` classes. I changed a lot of `self` to `self.view`. The life cycle of a `UIViewController` is a bit more complex than a UIView, so I ended up moving some initialization code from the designated initializer to the `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` methods in my `UIViewController` subclasses.

Response to comment: In my apps many pages have unique interactive features, so I write a unique `UIViewController` subclass to manage those features. Some pages will have the same features but different content. These will just use multiple instances of one `UIViewController` subclass. My model object will make these `UIViewController` subclasses and populate them with the appropriate content.

In other words, there's no need to write a new `UIViewController` subclass for every page. Only as many as you have unique functionality on a page. If your page doesn't do anything, you could even just use `UIViewController` without subclassing.

Comment: the problem i think with that is that i don't subclass uiview, and there's only one uiviewcontroller.  it just swaps views in and out, and takes care of whatever needs to be done for each page.  it seemed like it would be a pain to make a uiviewcontroller class for each page.